# Getting details on printers with SNMP?

Tags: hardware, printer, snmp

Under which OID is such detailed information on the make, model and features of the printer usually found?

I have to answer this question I have been researching and have installed the following

`apt update`

And

`sudo apt-get install snmpd snmp libsnmp-dev -y`

I have added the wifi printer and then ran `snmpwalk -v 2c -c public localhost`, and get this:

```
asir3@Asir03:~$ snmpwalk -v 2c -c public 127.0.0.1
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0 = STRING: "Linux Asir03 5.11.0-38-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 24 14:03:54 UTC 2021 x86_64"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.2.0 = OID: iso.3.6.1.4.1.8072.3.2.10
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0 = Timeticks: (381131) 1:03:31.31
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.4.0 = STRING: "Me <me@example.org>"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0 = STRING: "Asir03"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.6.0 = STRING: "Sitting on the Dock of the Bay"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.7.0 = INTEGER: 72
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.8.0 = Timeticks: (1) 0:00:00.01
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.2.1 = OID: iso.3.6.1.6.3.10.3.1.1
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.2.2 = OID: iso.3.6.1.6.3.11.3.1.1
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.2.3 = OID: iso.3.6.1.6.3.15.2.1.1
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.2.4 = OID: iso.3.6.1.6.3.1
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.2.5 = OID: iso.3.6.1.6.3.16.2.2.1
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.2.6 = OID: iso.3.6.1.2.1.49
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.2.7 = OID: iso.3.6.1.2.1.50
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.2.8 = OID: iso.3.6.1.2.1.4
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.2.9 = OID: iso.3.6.1.6.3.13.3.1.3
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.2.10 = OID: iso.3.6.1.2.1.92
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.3.1 = STRING: "The SNMP Management Architecture MIB."
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.3.2 = STRING: "The MIB for Message Processing and Dispatching."
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.3.3 = STRING: "The management information definitions for the SNMP User-based Security Model."
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.3.4 = STRING: "The MIB module for SNMPv2 entities"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.3.5 = STRING: "View-based Access Control Model for SNMP."
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.3.6 = STRING: "The MIB module for managing TCP implementations"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.3.7 = STRING: "The MIB module for managing UDP implementations"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.3.8 = STRING: "The MIB module for managing IP and ICMP implementations"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.3.9 = STRING: "The MIB modules for managing SNMP Notification, plus filtering."
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.3.10 = STRING: "The MIB module for logging SNMP Notifications."
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.4.1 = Timeticks: (1) 0:00:00.01
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.4.2 = Timeticks: (1) 0:00:00.01
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.4.3 = Timeticks: (1) 0:00:00.01
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.4.4 = Timeticks: (1) 0:00:00.01
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.4.5 = Timeticks: (1) 0:00:00.01
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.4.6 = Timeticks: (1) 0:00:00.01
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.4.7 = Timeticks: (1) 0:00:00.01
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.4.8 = Timeticks: (1) 0:00:00.01
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.4.9 = Timeticks: (1) 0:00:00.01
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.4.10 = Timeticks: (1) 0:00:00.01
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.1.0 = Timeticks: (809120) 2:14:51.20
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.2.0 = Hex-STRING: 07 E5 0C 06 0C 30 1A 00 2B 01 00 
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.3.0 = INTEGER: 393216
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.4.0 = STRING: "BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-38-generic root=UUID=94ba76e9-5ced-410f-adc5-1459d6d691f6 ro quiet splash"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.5.0 = Gauge32: 1
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.6.0 = Gauge32: 221
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.7.0 = INTEGER: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.7.0 = No more variables left in this MIB View (It is past the end of the MIB tree)
```

But I don't know what to look for the OID of the make, model and feature.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your question title asks for details of a printer job. Your question body asks for details of an attached printer. Usually I'd expect details of both to be found using CUPS rather than SNMP, but I must admit I've never checked the server MIB

Comment: thank you very much but my teacher told us that it must be SNMP.

Comment: Read `man -k snmp`

Comment: Network printers might support SNMP directly

Comment: have you tried to run `snmpwalk -v 2c -c public print-wifi-ip` ? because running snmpwalk on localhost will give information about localhost.

Comment: As Archemar says, you need to query the printer itself, not your linux sever.   You also need to find snmp MIB documentation for your particular printer(s) so you know what OID(s) to request and how to interpret the results.  Printer manufactures like to define their own proprietary non-standards for stuff like this, it helps with vendor lock-in and in selling their proprietary management tools. They have little incentive and no desire to make this easy for you.